# C# exporting from listview to csv - Excel application vs. FileStream

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, csv

I just have a curiosity question more than anything. I am working on a wpf app that exports from a listview to a csv. The code I wrote (which works) is below:

```
        private void Launch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        oExcel.Visible = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oWorkBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)oExcel.ActiveSheet;

        int row = 2; //allow for header row
        int column = 1;

        oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Name";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "CPU";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "RAM";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "IP Address";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Subnet Mask";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Port Group";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 7] = "Default Gateway";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 8] = "DNS";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 9] = "Description";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 10] = "Template";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 11] = "Host";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 12] = "Site";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 13] = "Folder";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 14] = "DataStore";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 15] = "Patch Method";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 16] = "HDD1Size";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 17] = "HDD1Format";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 18] = "HDD2Size";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 19] = "HDD2Format";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 20] = "HDD3Size";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 21] = "HDD3Format";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 22] = "HDD4Size";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 23] = "HDD4Format";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 24] = "HDD5Size";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 25] = "HDD5Format";


        foreach (var oVM in MyItems)
        {
            oSheet.Cells[row, column] = oVM.Name;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 1)] = oVM.CPU;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 2)] = oVM.RAM;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 3)] = oVM.IP;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 4)] = oVM.Subnet;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 5)] = oVM.PortGroup;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 6)] = oVM.Gateway;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 7)] = oVM.DNS;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 8)] = oVM.Description;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 9)] = oVM.Template;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 10)] = oVM.Host;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 11)] = oVM.Site;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 12)] = oVM.Folder;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 13)] = oVM.Datastore;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 14)] = oVM.Patch;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 15)] = oVM.HDD1Size;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 16)] = oVM.HDD1Format;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 17)] = oVM.HDD2Size;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 18)] = oVM.HDD2Format;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 19)] = oVM.HDD3Size;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 20)] = oVM.HDD3Format;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 21)] = oVM.HDD4Size;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 22)] = oVM.HDD4Format;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 23)] = oVM.HDD5Size;
            oSheet.Cells[row, (column + 24)] = oVM.HDD5Format;
            row++;
        }

        oExcel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\example", 6);
    }
```

As mentioned, this works, but is slow. I have Excel set to visible during the testing phase, and noticed it takes about 7 seconds just to open. Then another 2 to fill 10 rows.

I am also writing code to do the reverse, import from excel into the listview. For this, I used a StreamReader object, and the result is almost immediate. So I thought changing the code for the export would allow me the same speed. I tried this code:

```
            FileStream srcFS;
        srcFS = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\testingout.csv", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter srcWrt = new StreamWriter(srcFS, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();
            header.Append("Name").Append(',')
                  .Append("CPU").Append(',')
                  .Append("RAM").Append(',')
                  .Append("IP Address").Append(',')
                  .Append("Port Group").Append(',')
                  .Append("Default Gateway").Append(',')
                  .Append("DNS").Append(',')
                  .Append("Description").Append(',')
                  .Append("Template").Append(',')
                  .Append("Host").Append(',')
                  .Append("Site").Append(',')
                  .Append("Folder").Append(',')
                  .Append("Datastore").Append(',')
                  .Append("Patch").Append(',')
                  .Append("HDD1Size").Append(',')
                  .Append("HDD1Format").Append(',')
                  .Append("HDD2Size").Append(',')
                  .Append("HDD2Format").Append(',')
                  .Append("HDD3Size").Append(',')
                  .Append("HDD3Format").Append(',')
                  .Append("HDD4Size").Append(',')
                  .Append("HDD4Format").Append(',')
                  .Append("HDD5Size").Append(',')
                  .Append("HDDFormat").Append(',');

        srcWrt.WriteLine(header);

        foreach (MyItem item in MyItems)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.Append(item.Name).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.CPU).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.RAM).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.IP).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.Subnet).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.PortGroup).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.Gateway).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.DNS).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.Description).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.Template).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.Host).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.Site).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.Folder).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.Datastore).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.Patch).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.HDD1Size).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.HDD1Format).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.HDD2Size).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.HDD2Format).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.HDD3Size).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.HDD3Format).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.HDD4Size).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.HDD4Format).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.HDD5Size).Append(',')
                       .Append(item.HDD5Format);
            srcWrt.WriteLine(builder);
        }

MessageBox.Show("Task Complete");
```

But is seems exponentially slower, like 40 seconds to return the Message Box. Also, I noticed that even though the loop is complete, and shows the Message, it seems the stream is still writing. If I open the file too quickly is states it is in use by "Another User". So by the time the file is available to me it is actually closer to a minute.

I'm just wondering why the difference in speed read vs write using FileStream. Is it something I borked on implementation, or is this a known issue? If interacting with Excel is the way to go (I'd rather not as not all machines may have Excel installed) is there a way to shorten that initial 6 or 7 second delay?

Comment: When you profiled it, which bit was slow? The population of the `StringBuilder` or the `WriteLine`? What is `MyItems.Count()`?

Comment: try something like this: https://ctrlv.it/id/71935/2944207925, It's from my student's project, and i think it's fast.

Comment: I think, instead of FileStream and StreamWriter, you could just type `File.WriteAllText( <path> , builder.ToString())`,  and istead of  `srcWrt.WriteLine(builder)` builder.AppendLine("");

Comment: also, since Net 1.1, we don't use StringBuilder for know count of concats, so instead of Append Append Append etc, just write AppendLine( string1 + string2 + .. + string_last), should be faster.

Comment: @sTrenat -- I don't think that's right.  I think `StringBuilder` should be significantly faster than concatentation using the `+` operator, unless you're dealing with a trivial number of iterations.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306822/how-to-improve-string-concatenation-performance-in-visual-c

Comment: @Hambone - I think so, if compiler can count how many concatentation will be made, and how long will be string, he will compress this to **one** IL instruction, which will be faster that 20x append on stringBuilder. StringBuilder have advantege when comes to concate strings in loops like for/foreach/linq etc. There is realy no advantege if you could make everything as one long expresion with `+`

Comment: but yeah, this isn't bottleneck here. He should just try make everything without StreamWriter and FileStream.

Comment: Thanks, all, for the suggestions. The StringBuilder was coming back almost instantly, it was the WriteLine that was causing the issues. I tried sTrenat's suggestion of File.WriteAllText after the entire StringBuilder loop is complete, and this was much faster. I tested with a larger collections (1000 rows * 25 columns) and was just under 3 seconds for execution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with rewriting your function to:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("Name").Append(',')
        .Append("CPU").Append(',')
        .Append("RAM").Append(',')
        .Append("IP Address").Append(',')
        .Append("Port Group").Append(',')
        .Append("Default Gateway").Append(',')
        .Append("DNS").Append(',')
        .Append("Description").Append(',')
        .Append("Template").Append(',')
        .Append("Host").Append(',')
        .Append("Site").Append(',')
        .Append("Folder").Append(',')
        .Append("Datastore").Append(',')
        .Append("Patch").Append(',')
        .Append("HDD1Size").Append(',')
        .Append("HDD1Format").Append(',')
        .Append("HDD2Size").Append(',')
        .Append("HDD2Format").Append(',')
        .Append("HDD3Size").Append(',')
        .Append("HDD3Format").Append(',')
        .Append("HDD4Size").Append(',')
        .Append("HDD4Format").Append(',')
        .Append("HDD5Size").Append(',')
        .Append("HDDFormat").Append(',');
        .Append(Environment.NewLine);

foreach (MyItem item in MyItems) 
{  
    builder.Append(item.Name).Append(',')
        .Append(item.CPU).Append(',') 
        .Append(item.RAM).Append(',')
        .Append(item.IP).Append(',')
        .Append(item.Subnet).Append(',')
        .Append(item.PortGroup).Append(',')
        .Append(item.Gateway).Append(',') 
        .Append(item.DNS).Append(',')
        .Append(item.Description).Append(',')
        .Append(item.Template).Append(',')
        .Append(item.Host).Append(',')
        .Append(item.Site).Append(',')
        .Append(item.Folder).Append(',') 
        .Append(item.Datastore).Append(',') 
        .Append(item.Patch).Append(',')
        .Append(item.HDD1Size).Append(',') 
        .Append(item.HDD1Format).Append(',')
        .Append(item.HDD2Size).Append(',') 
        .Append(item.HDD2Format).Append(',')
        .Append(item.HDD3Size).Append(',') 
        .Append(item.HDD3Format).Append(',')
        .Append(item.HDD4Size).Append(',') 
        .Append(item.HDD4Format).Append(',') 
        .Append(item.HDD5Size).Append(',')
        .Append(item.HDD5Format)
        .Append(Environment.NewLine);
} 

using(FileStream srcFS = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\testingout.csv", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using(StreamWriter srcWrt = new StreamWriter(srcFS, System.Text.Encoding.Default)) 
    {
        srcWrt.WriteText(builder);
    } 
}
```

I'd guess it's that you write to file every loop that slows down your code. If you instead write to file in one batch, when the string is complete. That is usually a better option